# Cannot instantiate FXML Loader with Gradle

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So, I am trying to use Gradle to create a JavaFX app in conjunction to using FXML to design the GUI.

I have successfully added JFX 13 as a dependency, but cannot get my FXML loader to work

here is my gradle build

[Here is my Gradle Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTkyG.png)

Note I did not select JavaFX application when creating my project.

My code

public class SessionManager extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Cannot resolve symbol FXML loader, is the error

Comment: please don't post (nearto) unreadable screenshots - instead c&p the text content ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the `javafx.fxml` module in your Gradle file.

Answer (score -2):

When I select New File... FXML is not an available selection. When I have FXML files in my project, launching Scene Builder to edit them is not an option. This is despite having both the "JavaFX 2 Support" and "JavaFX 2 Scene Builder" and even "Monet - SceneBuildre Designer" plugins active.

Comment: doesn't look like an answer .. is it?